# Linux "rpl" command doesn't replace text

Tags: linux, grep, replace

I'm using `rpl` program in linux to replace `date(` with `pdate(` in some files.
But it says `A Total of 0 matches replaced in 1 file searched.`
while grep output for `date(` is:

```
ariyan@ariyan-laptop:/var/www/moodle21$ grep -wR 'date(' admin/uploaduser.php
$today = make_timestamp(date('Y', $today), date('m', $today), date('d', $today), 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm using `rpl` as this:

```
rpl -wR 'date(' 'pdate(' admin/uploaduser.php
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Cross post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73322/linux-rpl-command-doesnt-replace-text

Comment: And http://superuser.com/questions/351663/linux-rpl-command-doesnt-replace-text

Comment: I flagged as crossposting, already answered elsewhere (SU).

Answer (score 1):

The `-w` flag makes it require word boundaries, and "between `(` and `'`" may not be a word boundary. Try `sed 's/\bdate(/pdate(/g'` instead.